Calculate work done
When we kick anything like a football or hit a ball, how do we calculate the work done? For example let a football be kicked, and it covers 100m distance. Suppose the force applied was 100N. Calculate the work done. Can we calculate the work done or do we need some other information?

To calculate the work done, you need to know the force and displacement vs time during the interval in which the foot and ball are in contact.

Since the force is not applied over the distance traveled, you can't simply multiply the force times distance.
What I would do is try to estimate the velocity of the ball shortly after being kicked or hit and apply the work energy theorem which is the net work done on an object equals its change in kinetic energy. The work done will be, given an initial velocity prior to kicking or hitting the ball of zero,
$$W=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$$
where $m$ is the mass of the ball and $v$ is velocity shorty after kicking or hitting the ball.
Hope this helps.

We define work as the product of the force applied to an object, and the distance over which that force is applied, in the direction of force.
We have the formula for work:
$$W = F\cdot d \cdot \cos \theta,$$
where $F$ is the magnitude of the force applied, $d$ is the distance over which the force is applied, and $\theta$ is the angle between the force's direction and the direction of the movement.
For your example, the force $F$ is $100N$ and the distance $d$ is $100m.$ But when you kick a football, you apply the force over a very short distance when your foot is in contact with the ball.
So, we might have, for example, the contact distance $d_{\mathrm{contact}} = 0.1\,\mathrm{m}$, so that
$$W=F\cdot d_{\mathrm{contact}}$$
$$ = 100\mathrm{N} \times 0.1\mathrm{m} = 10 \mathrm{J}.$$
So, in conclusion, we must know the exact distance over which the duration of the kick of the ball takes place, to know the work done during the kick.


Note that this is for constant $F$ and constant angle $\theta$ relative to the path

The distance d (100m ) of the kick can be determined using kinematic equations (assume simple projectile motion) with the football is kicked from the ground y =0:
$$d= \frac {v^2 \sin {2\theta}}{g}$$
where v is the initial velocity after the kick and $\theta$ is the angle with the horizontal.
$$v^2= \frac {gd}{sin 2\theta}$$
The change in kinetic energy due to kicking the ball is the work done kicking the ball and is given by
$$\Delta KE = \frac 1 2 \frac {mgd}{sin 2\theta} = W$$

This is not complete, it only covers the "work" in the vertical direction (inverted commas since work is not a vector quantity). There's also some amount of work due to the horizontal motion.

@Allure Thanks. I have update my answer
